# File.copy over lan with credentials

Tags: asp.net

I have to copy a file to a pc in a lan network. Let's say I have to copy a file from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.3. I have to copy in a folder named 'folder'. 
So I have a folder with a path 192.168.1.3/folder. This folder has credentials username and password.
I saw already ways to do this like the following:

```
using (new Impersonator("username", "domain", "pass"))
{
         File.Copy(@"192.168.1.2\file.txt", @"192.168.1.3\folder\file.txt");
}
```

what is the domain in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain is (usually) the name of the Active Directory domain. You can open the Control Panel, make sure you're in icon view, click on System, then view the domain in "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings". If it ends in `.local`, `.net` or `.com` or something similar you may be able to leave the part off.

By the way, usually when using [UNC network paths](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm) like that, you'll lead with a double slash before the computer name. Ex:

```
using (new Impersonator("username", "domain", "pass"))
{
     File.Copy(@"\\192.168.1.2\file.txt", @"\\192.168.1.3\folder\file.txt");
}
```